# How to select a lens for reading very small font characters

Tags: camera, computer-vision

I am trying to implement an OCR / OCV algorithm for inspecting printed text in black ink on a white background. The text size is ranging from 3 pt. to 6 pt. I tried first to capture images with a 5 MP monochrome camera using an 8 mm, 12 mm and 16 mm lens but I could not get the characters with good clarity. I repeated the same test with 10 MP camera also considering that higher pixel depth will give more information but I got same results.

I'm not sure, how I can get a clearer image. Whether a 5 MP / 10 MP is enough and if there is any way to determine the lens to be used in such application.

The FOV for inspection is about 300 x 250 mm and the working distance I considered from approx. 400 mm to 650 mm.

Due to copyright concerns I cannot post the image of the object under inspection.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple geometry. It is:

```
3pt =~ 1mm.
```

Assuming you want to have 10 pixels to cover each character, your IFOV needs to be:

```
IFOV =~ (font_width / 10) / distance = 0.1 / 650 =~ 0.15 milliradians / pixel.
```

For the work area width you mention, the horizontal field of view is:

```
FOV = 2 * atan((300 / 2) / 650) =~ 453 milliradians =~ 26 deg
```

So the minimal (horizontal) sensor resolution you'd need is:

```
Width = 453 / 0.15 = 3020 pixels.
```

Thus a 10MP sensor should be quite sufficient, and 5MP one may be adequate.

To choose the lens, from the above spec for the FOV, and the format (width, height) of your choice of sensor, you can work out by the same simple trigonometry the needed focal length. Finally, among all lenses matching that focal length that are available for your camera mount, you need to choose one that (a) can be focused at the distance of interest and (b) has an adequate [Optical Transfer Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transfer_function) such that one line can be resolved at the above IFOV.

In practice, after running the math and looking at catalogs, you'll end up with several candidate lenses. My advice would then be to get samples and try them out on your on setup, and specifically with the particular lighting rig you'll be using, before making a final decision. Depending on your particular project, factors influencing the choice, in addition (obviously) to the cost of the lens + sensor combination, may be size/weight, sensitivity to environment conditions (temperature, humidity, vibrations), availability and lead time for sourcing, etc.